# Can i pull docker same image every time from git using dockerOperator in airlfow?

Tags: airflow, dockeroperator

When i pull same docker image second time using dockeroperator, it is retrieving from local, but i want dockeroperator to pull image from repo every time, is it possible in airflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `DockerOperator` to pull the image on every run, set its `force_pull` parameter to `True`. See the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.9/_api/airflow/operators/docker_operator/index.html).

Note, Docker will not download the full image again if the local copy of the image is up to date.

Comment: No. my question was wat to do to pull the image if it is updated. Airflow is not pulling the image automatically if it is updated

Comment: @user16839305 With force_pull=True it will check on every task run. If the image was updated it will download it, if not then it will not download it.